# Mean Stack Data Aggregation, Not Displaying on Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean

I am using the mean stack and im aggregating data in the db to display on the front end.
I am counting all the records of a db collection and returning a number to be displayed.

However i am not getting it to work on the angular frontend:

The controller and router for the aggregation:
Route:

```
router.get('/DAFacilityCntRpts', DAFacilityController.DAFacility_count_reports)
```

Controller:

```
exports.DAFacility_count_reports = (req, res) => {
  DAFacility.aggregate([
    {
      '$project': {
        'eventName': 1, 
        'reportStatus': 1
      }
    }, {
      '$count': 'NoOfDaFacilityReports'
    }
  ]).then((DAFacility) => {
    res.send(DAFacility);
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.send(e);
  });
};
```

and it returns this on postman:

```
[
    {
        "NoOfDaFacilityReports": 4
    }
]
```

However when trying to get that value to be displayed on the front end it doesnt.
services:

```
noOfDAFacReports() {
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/DAFacilityCntRpts")
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
    }))
  }
```

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    })
    console.log(this.aggregationFac)*/

    this.aggregation.noOfDAFacReports().subscribe(res=>
      {
        this.aggregationFac = res;
      })
  }
```

component.html:

```
<h3>Number of Facility Damage Assessment Reports Made: {{aggregationFac.NoOfDaFacilityReports}}</h3>
```

please let me know where i am going wrong

Comment: The API response is an array. What is `aggregationFac` type? If it is an array, you can use `aggregationFac[0].NoOfDaFacilityReports`.

Comment: Common mistake, MongoDB aggregate always return an array. You will have to `aggregationFac[0].NoOfDaFacilityReports`. This is why Types are very helpful instead of just using `any` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved in comments, just writing it here so that people in future can find this.

MongoDB aggregate always returns an `array`, so you will have to use

`aggregationFac[0].NoOfDaFacilityReports`

Types are helpful in angular, rather than using `any`